# How can I proxy a port for a network service

Tags: networking, proxy

Imagine you have 2 servers, one is serving network service on port 800 and other one is doing another service on port 801.

You use public IP for both of them, both servers have 2 network interfaces and are also on a private LAN connected to each other. You want to save one public IP (because IPv4 addresses aren't cheap these days) so you would like one server to "proxy" the other server, so that there was only 1 public IP address of server A that would be listening on both 800 and 801, but traffic of port 801 would be redirected to server B.

How can I do this? I am not looking for web proxy, the service in question may be any potential TCP network service. On linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up some sort of NAT or forwarding on server A. On Linux you could do that using iptables, but that wouldn't be very simple.

A simple alternative is using `rinetd`. The configuration consists of a single line:

```
# bind ip     port destination ip  port
206.125.69.81 801  1.2.3.4         801
```

This will work for all TCP-based protocols, I don't think rinetd does UDP. Check your distribution's package manager for the package. Usually configuration can be found in `/etc/rinetd.conf`